# Configuring Blogs on a multi site Magento setup

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, server

I have two websites say abc.com and pqr.com running from the same Magento installation. Now I want to create blogs for each of those domains through wordpress for which I have created a folder "blogs" in the root Magento directory and installed two instances of wordpress in folders named blogs/abc and blogs/pqr.

How do I configure my .htaccess or index.php in the root directory so that requests to www.abc.com/blog and www.pqr.com/blog are routed to the folders blogs/abc and blogs/pqr respectively.

Please note that I want my blog URL's to be of the form abc.com/blog and not blog.abc.com

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


#Redirect Blogs

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(abc|pqr)\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^blog(?:/(.*))?$ /blogs/%1/$1 [NC,L]


############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]




</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(abc|pqr)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog(?:/(.*))?$ /blogs/%1/$1 [NC,L]
```

---

Please rearrange the end part of your .htaccess as

```
#Redirect Blogs

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(abc|pqr)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog(?:/(.*))?$ /blogs/%1/$1 [NC,L]

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
## but never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Please note that the `RewriteCond` and the immediately following `RewriteRule` come together to form a redirect rule. You were putting the blog related rules right between them breaking that functionality.

Comment: When I write this code just above ############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]   - requesting http://www.example.com/blog/redirects to http://www/example.com where example = abc.

Comment: Please, post your current htaccess in the question so that I can understand your rules better.

Comment: Added the redirect section from my .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the vhost configuration (usually /etc/apaches/sites-enabled/abc), just enter

```
Alias /blog /var/www/blogs/abc
```

into the vhost for abc.com and analog for the vhost of pqr.com.

You also need to have mod_alias enabled. This is not possible to be done in a .htaccess file, see also [this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

Comment: I have created vhost.conf in /var/www/vhosts/abc/conf/ and eneterd just the line stated above. Do I need to restart the server?